# How to select the value from an attribute that has a colon in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I am working with xslt to handle the results that are returned from a web service. I first need to determine which web service the results are for.  I know that the tag platformCore:record has the attribute "xsi:type="listRel:Contact or "xsi:type="listEmp:Employee".  I am trying to select the value that the attribute is storing, but the colon seems to be causing some issues when I attempt to select the value.

Here is what I tried, but fails to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="Type"><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='searchResponse']//*[local-name()='searchResult']//*[local-name()='recordList']//*[local-name()='record']@xsi:type"/></xsl:variable>

<root>
<test><xsl:value-of select="$Type"/></test>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a simple sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResponse:searchResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2012_2.platform.webservices.itsthesuite.com" 
                               xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                               xmlns:searchResponse="urn:messages_2012_2.platform.webservices.itsthesuite.com"
                               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <platformCore:searchResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2012_2.platform.webservices.itsthesuite.com">
    <platformCore:status isSuccess="true"/>
    <platformCore:totalRecords>1</platformCore:totalRecords>
    <platformCore:recordList>
      <platformCore:record internalId="154098" xsi:type="listRel:Contact" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2012_2.lists.webservices.itsthesuite.com">
        <listRel:entityId>John Smith</listRel:entityId>
        <listRel:firstName>John</listRel:firstName>
        <listRel:lastName>Smith</listRel:lastName>
        <listRel:phone>(777) 777-7777</listRel:phone>
        <listRel:email>john.smith@yormoms.com</listRel:email>
      </platformCore:record>
    </platformCore:recordList>
  </platformCore:searchResult>
</searchResponse:searchResponse>
```

I need the solution to work for this sample as well.

Employee Sample

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2012_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:searchResponse="urn:messages_2012_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<platformCore:searchResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2012_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" >
<platformCore:status isSuccess="true"/>
<platformCore:totalRecords>1</platformCore:totalRecords>
<platformCore:recordList>
<platformCore:record internalId="158778" xsi:type="listEmp:Employee" xmlns:listEmp="urn:employees_2012_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
<listEmp:entityId>331sfds Dipo  Chaponda</listEmp:entityId>
<listEmp:salutation>Mr.</listEmp:salutation>
<listEmp:firstName>Dipo</listEmp:firstName>
<listEmp:lastName>Chaponda</listEmp:lastName>
<listEmp:email>dchapond@youmm.com</listEmp:email>
</platformCore:record>
</platformCore:recordList>
</platformCore:searchResult>
</searchResponse>
```

Comment: The things before the colons are called "namespaces".  Also, _"the colon seems to be causing some issues"_ isn't enough of a description of the problem.  Please be more specific.

Comment: Also, the attribute `xsi:type` does not contain the value of anything. It describes the datatype the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select an attribute using local name similarly to what you are already doing, but by prefacing the * with an @:

```
@*[local-name() = 'type']
```

However, littering your XPaths with `local-name() =` and double slashes is not a good practice.  You should use namespaces properly, and use precise paths when they are known, although it seems that is not an option for the elements in your case because they are using different namespaces in the two examples. This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="sr pc xsi"
                >

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="Type">
      <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'searchResponse']/
                            *[local-name() = 'searchResult']/
                            *[local-name() = 'recordList']/
                            *[local-name() = 'record']/
                            @xsi:type"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <root>
      <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Type"/>
      </test>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces the expected result:

```
<root>
  <test>listRel:Contact</test>
</root>
```

Comment: What is exclude-result-prefixes="sr pc xsi" doing in your solution?

Comment: It presents the namespaces for those three prefixes from being output to the result document.

Comment: Is it possible to make your solution work for both the 1st sample and this sample at the same time?  I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean the 1st sample and this sample? There's only one sample.

Comment: I just posted the second one.

Comment: The sample was missing the namespace but I added them.  When I use your solution on the employee sample and select the attribute xsi:type the value comes back as empty.

Comment: Ok, well since both samples are using different namespaced, I guess you do need to use `local-name()`, but you don't need to for `xsi:type`, because the `xsi` namespace is the same in both examples (and will almost always be the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26507/discussion-between-pitchblack408-and-jlrishe)